# Where may I find API description for TrueVFS framework?

Tags: java, truevfs

I'm about to implement the TrueVFS api into my our application but as it happens the descriptions for this framework has dissapeared, it was earlier accessible from truevfs.java.net. A lot of information is accessible via Wayback Machine, ie. [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20161105060508/https://truevfs.java.net/index.html), also some parts of the [API documentation](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20160708164250/http://truevfs.java.net:80/apidocs/index.html). However not all pages of the API documentation are indexed in Wayback Machine. Does anyone have any clue as to where I might find this information?

Thanks.

ps. I've also contacted the guy who made the TrueVFS API, awaiting his response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been moved to [this](http://truevfs.net/) address, but seems to be abandoned